# What does question mark mean?

Tags: elixir

Consider following module

```
defmodule Parse do

  def number([ ?- | tail ]), do: _number_digits(tail, 0) * -1
  def number([ ?+ | tail ]), do: _number_digits(tail, 0)
  def number(str),           do: _number_digits(str, 0)

  defp _number_digits([], value), do: value
  defp _number_digits([ digit | tail ], value) when digit in '0123456789' do
    _number_digits(tail, value*10 + digit - ?0)
  end
  defp _number_digits([ non_digit | _ ], _) do
    raise "Invalid digit '#{[non_digit]}'"
  end

end
```

When I import the file into shell and execute following statement:

```
iex(3)> Parse.number('123')
```

as output I've got

```
123
```

What I really do not understand is this line:

```
value*10 + digit - ?0
```

What does ?0 really mean? I know, when I write ?x on shell, it shows me the code point like

```
iex(13)> ?5
53
iex(14)> ?t
116
```

The ?0 has code point -48. The example above with 123, the calculation with first iteration number 1 would looks like(value*10 + digit - ?0):

```
0 * 10 + 1 - 48
```

When I calculate by myself, I would get as result -47 but I've got 1, why?

Comment: From google search, copy and paste: "the question mark in the function name indicates that the return value will be a boolean"

Comment: It can not be a boolean, because it returns a number.

Comment: @EvanCarslake  That is referring to a question mark in the function name. He's asking about a question mark in the argument list. Two different things.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`?` followed by a character gives you that character's Unicode code point value.

The `- ?0` done in the second clause of the `_number_digits` function subtracts the code point of the character '0' from the digit's code point value. This conveniently gives you the integer 0 for the digit '0', 1 for the digit '1', etc.

Thus, the entire `value*10 + digit - ?0` expression first multiples the running total (`value`) by 10 (since we're dealing with base-10 input strings), then adds the value for the current digit under consideration. This happens recursively until all digits of the input string are consumed, given you the integer represented by the input string.

Comment: When I write ` [x, y, z] = '123'`  into the iex, then it clarifies me, that digit use the code point value to calculate result.The power of pattern matching. Thanks so much.